# Confusion related to svm optimization

Tags: machine-learning, support-vector-machines

I was reading this[paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v22/zhang12d/zhang12d.pdf&ei=UpBpUfSnKZfJ4AODr4BA&usg=AFQjCNE4mUPPsSiyQBW5FY_IyeRT7Im9Og&sig2=pY3PIaolEYAfVTmLevmCuA&bvm=bv.45175338,d.dmg) related to kernel SVM. It states

**Support Vector Machine (SVM) (Cortes and Vap- nik, 1995) as the state-of-the-art classification algo- rithm has been widely applied in various scientific do- mains. The use of kernels allows the input samples to be mapped to a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert S- pace (RKHS), which is crucial to solving linearly non- separable problems. While kernel SVMs deliver the state-of-the-art results, the need to manipulate the k- ernel matrix imposes significant computational bottle- neck, making it difficult to scale up on large data.**

I didn't get what they mean by manipulate the kernel matrix. I mean lets say I am using the RBF kernel. Then my kernel matrix will have elements of the form

$exp^{\sigma {||x_i-x_j||}_2}{}$

which I can calculate once and then have it there. So what is meant by kernel manipulation

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article in question?

Comment: @MichaelGrant. I have added the link to the paper

Answer (score 2):

They are simply referring to the fact that the kernel matrix itself is a central quantity in the algorithm. The problem is that it is $O(n^2)$ in size, where $n$ is the number of points being examined. So the storage and computational requirements surrounding the kernel matrix rapidly become impractical as $n$ gets large.

Comment: Thats what I didn't get even in the linear svm, we can have the matrix which simply consists of the elements $x^Tx$. So it also consumes space isn't it?

Comment: For the linear SVM you never need to form the kernel.

Comment: I'm hoping someone else can provide a fuller answer---I am out of town an responding on my iPhone ;) Honestly I think context will help. Kernel methods are styled as a means of regaining efficiency. But it still requires solving a fuller QP.